# Modeling oop hierarchy for a game

Tags: javascript, oop

I thought of starting a html5 game development project. 
I started my game project with modelling it.
I came up with something like this.

```
Game

   Array of Entities
   Timer
   score
   some methods for initializing
   master draw
   master update


Entity

   Update
   Draw
```

What happens is that the master method(update or draw) calls the update/draw method on each entity.

The model seemed clean enough to me and i started to code but then i realized that there is no way of communication between different entities.

The update method of one entity would need to consider the state of other entities.

I have coded each update functions prototype with same set of arguments so that i can loop over the entities and call them easily.

Please can somebody suggest ways to overcome the problem.
What changes should be done to the model?
Also how do you get better at modelling software architecture and extending it.
How do you decide how much part of code to keep abstracted?

Comment: What I've done in the past is to have the `Game` pass an array of other `Entity` objects to each `Entity`'s update method. That didn't seem quite right to me, but I'm not sure, so hopefully someone can comment on that...

Comment: ya i also thought of it but it seemed to be hacky.

Answer (score 2):

Ok... that's a pretty broad question, and you're probably not going to get a definitive answer here. But genrally, you need to think of your game in terms of Model-View-[something else]. Here [Something else] can be ["Controller"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller) or ["ViewModel"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel), or something in-between.

The model, as referred to by the Model-View pattern (not as you refer to it above), knows about and maintains the game logic and none of the visual representation of it. Game logic includes score, level, players etc. Each View in your game (a view can be a score box, or a player character) has a reference to the model and extracts from the model the info it needs to render itself. That's how you share info between the views – through a centralized model (sometimes models have sub-models, in complex games, but start simple, with a single model class).

When you find that your views need some coordination of logic that's not inherently model-based, that's when you introduce controller or viewModel logic.

I'm sure if you google "game design patterns" (with or without "javascript") you'll find all kinds of interesting tutorials on the matter.

** EDIT: **

In your case, you probably should think of **Game** as your controller. At initialization, it would instanciate a **Model**, which is where you put the score and timer logic (so, not inside **Game**. Then it would instanciate the array of **Entities**, giving each one the instance of **Model**. In the update method, **Game** would invoke appropriate methods to update **Model**, then call `update()` on each **Entity**, which would read the state out of **Model** and redraw accordingly.

There's a variation of this where **Game** doesn't call `update()` on entities, and instead, changes to **Model** trigger events that are subscribed to by each **Entity**.

Comment: can you suggest some changes to my model?

Comment: so its as simple as storing the game in each entity so transferring the info.
But does'nt it fails the whole concept of oop.
If we make game a instance of an entity.Does;nt that fails the whole idea of "HAS A" relationship.

Comment: Game wouldn't be an instance of Entity. Game _instantiates_ entity and gives it Model. That is, inside Game, you have `new Entity(model)` (I'm assuming Entity here is some View of some aspect of the game, like a character or a score box). So in that sense, Game has a relationship with Entities/Views and Models. But Models don't know anything about Entities. And, Entities _do) know about Model, but usually don't know anything about other Entities that are present.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem before, too. What I've done is give one entity a reference to the other player (in a game with just two entities), and/or give the entity a reference to the whole game model. By giving the entity the whole game model, it can see its surroundings and other entities around it and act accordingly.